# Loading data from multiple s3 folders selectively into table in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql, amazon-emr

I have a s3 bucket with multiple folders say, A, B and there are also some other folders. Folder structure is as below:

```
s3://buckets/AGGREGATED_STUDENT_REPORT/data/A/,
s3://buckets/AGGREGATED_STUDENT_REPORT/data/B/ etc.
```

And inside these two folders daily report gets generated in another folder like run_date=2019-01-01, so the resultant folder structure is something like below:

```
  s3://buckets/AGGREGATED_STUDENT_REPORT/data/A/run_date=2019-01-01/..,
  s3://buckets/AGGREGATED_STUDENT_REPORT/data/B/run_date=2019-01-01/..
```

Now in hive, I want to create a external table taking the data generated on last day of every month in only these two folders, ignoring others as follows:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE STUDENT_SUMMARY
 (
   ROLL_NUM    STRING,
   CLASS  STRING,
   REMARKS STRING,
   LAST_UPDATED STRING,
 )
  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
  STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION  's3://AGGREGATED_STUDENT_REPORT/data/*/run_date=2018-12-31';
```

But in the above query I am not able to figure out how to process group of selected folders.

Comment: Create two tables and a view with `union all`

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you can copy the folders to HDFS. 
Two reasons:

a) You can create just 1 folder in HDFS and copy all the A,b,c, etc into the same HDFS folder and use the same under your location parameter.

b) I am guessing the query performance would be better if the data resides in HDFS rather than S3.